# Error using CORS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cors

I have been reading the questions on the stackoverflow regard CORS implementation for a couple weeks but I'm still stuck on a couple errors.  Any pointers in the right direction would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Here's what I have:

SERVER SETUP

```
public void doOptions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException {
//The following are CORS headers. Max age informs the 
//browser to keep the results of this call for 1 day.
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
//Tell the browser what requests we allow.
response.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS");
```

CLIENTSIDE Javascript
    
    
    OLVM Test Page

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">

function setMessage(){

msg = "";
var xmlHttp;
msg = msg + "110@@@B@~20@OLVM-GL-ACCOUNT@~20";
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST","http://MYSITE.ceco.com:2900/OLVM/OLVMGateway",false);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
xmlHttp.send(msg);
alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
return;
}


</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left"><font face="Arial" size="6"><b>OLVM - PBF </b></font></p>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit To Server" onClick= "setMessage()" >
</body>
</html>
```

OPTIONS HEADER info I see when debugging

```
Request URL:http://MYSITE.ceco.com:2900/OLVM/OLVMGateway
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:MYSITE.ceco.com:2900
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:86400
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 02 Jul 2014 12:13:41 GMT
```

POST HEADER info I see when debugging

```
Request URL:http://MYSITE.ceco.com:2900/OLVM/OLVMGateway
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:337
Content-Type:text/xml
Host:MYSITE.ceco.com:2900
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
```

Request Payload
    110@@@B@~20@OLVM-GL-ACCOUNT@~20
    Response Headersview source
    Content-Length:7
    Content-Type:text/html
   Date:Wed, 02 Jul 2014 12:13:41 GMT

ERROR I get
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://MYSITE.ceco.com:2900/OLVM/OLVMGateway. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. OLVM_V5.html:59

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://MYSITE.ceco.com:2900/OLVM/OLVMGateway'.

Comment: and now for the results???  also, how do you call this from js?

Comment: What are the "couple of errors"?

Comment: Lost my network connection, added errors that I see

Comment: I have a local html file with embeded javascript.  I'm seeing the two errors above when using IE8 and Chrome 35.0.1916.

Comment: Ok I have a doPost function that handles my POST responses so I’ll set those headers there too on the serverside and give it another shot.  I'll post my results.

Comment: Added the headers to the POST response an that did the trick. Works perfect thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding the headers to the OPTIONS response.

However, for the request to succeed you have to set those headers both on OPTIONS and on POST responses.

Also note that your code will not work in IE8 as it requires proprietary `XDomainRequest` object as you can see in [HTML5Rocks.com example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-making-a-cors-request):

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);

  } else {

    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;

  }
  return xhr;
}

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
if (!xhr) {
  throw new Error('CORS not supported');
}
```